# Do Statement-level AFTER triggers occur asynchronously after the statement returns?

Tags: postgresql, trigger

I'm using an `AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR TRUNCATE ... FOR EACH STATEMENT` trigger on a table to refresh a materialized view, and I'm concerned that it will significantly affect the performance of those statements.

Would an `INSERT` , for example, wait for the materialized view refresh to complete before returning?

Comment: Synchronous. Yes, the `insert` statement would "hang" until the materialized view was finished refreshing.

Comment: Dang, I don't suppose you know of any alternative methods that wouldn't block like that?

Comment: You could, for example, drop a row into a sort of housekeeping table and visit it from a scheduled job.  Once it finds this row there, it refreshes the MV.